what is the meaning of the "operation" field in multisig-transactions endpoints in the safe transaction service?
In the multisig-transactions endpoints' responses there is an operation field of type integer, for the most part it is equal to 0.
What is the meaning of the value in that field?

The operation field is an integer representing an ENUM to characterize the transaction: 0 corresponds to a call and 1 to a delegatecall.
Hope it answers your question? Best, Louis
